# Connection failed error when creating MySQL connection via PDO

Tags: php, pdo, insert, prepared-statement

I'm new to PDO and PHP. Can someone tell me what's wrong in my code. There is no error on browser it only shows (Connection Failed).

```
<?php

class Connect
{
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $database = "srs_electrical";
    private $dsn;
    public $con;
    public $stmt;

    function __construct()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->dsn = 'mysql:host = ' . $this->host . ';dbname = ' . $this->database;
            $this->con = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->user, $this->password);
            $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO comp_users VALUES(NULL,'Name','Email','Password')");
            $this->stmt->execute();
            echo 'connected';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
$con = new Connect();
?>
```

Comment: @Abdul, please consider choosing better titles for your questions. From the code it is evident that you apparently know how to insert, while your question is rather "why my code doesn't work".

Comment: Is there a reason you are not displaying the error from $e ?

Comment: @RohitGupta No. There is no reason. Let me update the code please. Thanks!

Comment: I know its a bit old, but did you try the solutions in the duplicate post

Comment: @RohitGupta Yes! I had. But no use.

Comment: The problem was with the connection string. ('mysql:host = '), There should be no space before and after = sign. This is the correct string ('mysql:host=').